# Why is my code getting an infinite loop?

Tags: python-2.7

```
minimunpaymonth = 0
balance = 4773
annualInterestRate = 0.2
def function(minimunpaymonth):
    global balance
    month = 1
    while month <= 12:
        balance = balance - minimunpaymonth
        anninterest = annualInterestRate/12 * balance
        balance = balance + anninterest
        month += 1
    return balance
while function(minimunpaymonth) >= 0:
    minimunpaymonth += 10
print "Lowest Payment: " + str(minimunpaymonth)
```

the second while loop is infinite and i dont know why. the first is ok because i have ran it

when the loop increases minimunpaymonth, value of balance goes down, so there will be a moment when balance is negative

```
def function(minimunpaymonth, balance, annualInterestRate):
    month = 1
    while month <= 12:
        balance = balance - minimunpaymonth
        anninterest = annualInterestRate/12 * balance
        balance = balance + anninterest
        month += 1
    return balance
while function(minimunpaymonth, balance, annualInterestRate) >= 0:
    minimunpaymonth += 10
print "Lowest Payment: " + str(minimunpaymonth)
```

ok i just solved it. i change the function to give 3 arguments instead of 1

Comment: Hint: `minimunpaymonth` starts at 0. Is it going up or down in that loop?

Comment: Put a `print` statement inside `function` to check the value of `balance`. Then check that the value is correct.

Answer (score 1):

your second loop is checking to see if `minimunpaymonth` is `>= 0`, if it is then it performs the loop again.

Your `minimunpaymonth` will always be `>=0` because it starts at 0 & is only ever added to. There is no subtraction from this value.

Answer (score 0):

the second loop keeps adding to minimum payment, it will always be >= 0 till it reaches the numeric limit of the variable; however as the comment pointed out, the "function" could get less, but perhaps the interest rate always keeps the balance above zero and the minimum payments don't get it there -- plausible enough in real life!

Comment: if i add 10 to minimunpaymonth, the new balance value will be less than the old value

Comment: Perhaps the interest rate always keeps the balance higher than the minimum payment.  This is believable...; I edited answer above

Comment: i dont think so, if i write only the function and increase the value of minimunpaymonth manually, the balance value starts to go down till it becomes negative.
but the loop increases the value of both

Comment: I'm not an expert in this language, what I'd try is making an intermediate variable y = function() and then checking on y.... you could temporarily change the control to running a few times (say a for loop with ten runs and a printout) and see what happens.... To me, the syntax while function(minimunpaymonth) >= 0: does too much at once, and it is fine if it works, but clearly not if it doesn't....